# sed - Replacing characters within a line

Tags: regex, sed

I have some html links in a number of files that I need to alter:

```
      <a href="www.blah.edu/hello world of friends" class="blue">Hello World</a>
```

Say that the above links are located in test.txt.

I've been trying to find a one liner would that replace spaces with underscores *only* within the href link. So

```
      <a href="www.blah.edu/hello world of friends" class="blue">Hello World</a>
```

would need to be

```
      <a href="www.blah.edu/hello_world_of_friends" class="blue">Hello World</a>
```

This is as far as I've gotten, using sed:

```
     sed '/href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]*"/{s;\s;_;g}' test.txt
```

Of course, this produces:

```
     <a_href="www.blah.edu/hello_world"_class="blue">Hello_World</a>
```

And I understand why it does this. The /regex/ bit pulls the entire line into the pattern-space, and then s;;; is executed on the entire line, rather than just the bit I need.

How can I substitute spaces for underscores only within *href=* and *"*? Is there a better way to think about this than using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU Awk or Mawk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "href=\""; ORS = ""; FS = OFS = "\"" } NR > 1 { gsub(/ /, "_", $1); print RS } 1' file
```

Output:

```
  <a href="www.blah.edu/hello_world_of_friends" class="blue">Hello World</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I choose perl for this: you can put code in the replacement part and evaluate it.

```
perl -pe 's{(?<=href=")(.+?)(?=")}{ (my $x = $1) =~ s/\s/_/g; $x }ge' <<END
<a href="www.blah.edu/hello world of friends" class="blue">Hello World</a>
END
```

```
<a href="www.blah.edu/hello_world_of_friends" class="blue">Hello World</a>
```

With some explanation:

```
perl -pe '
    s{
        (?<=href=")  # starting where the preceding text is: href="
        (.+?)        # find a non-greedy sequence of chars until
        (?=")        # the closing quote is next.
    }{ 
        (my $x = $1) =~ s/\s/_/g;    # replace whitespace with underscore 
        $x                           # and replace with the new value
    }gex
'
```

Comment: That's interesting. My perl knowledge is very limited. You've just given me a reason to dig into it a ton more. Thanks!